# Ax X++ override dialog form field filter CustAccount

Tags: axapta, x++

I have a similar problem with my dialog but I am getting an error with no control calling method.

I am trying to override the lookup on dialog field of type CustAccount - what I want is the lookup to return all custTable records where the invoiceAccount is of a certain value.

Here is my code:

```
class AG_UpdateQuoteCust extends Runbase
{
DialogField                 dlgCust;
CustAccount                 newCust;
CustAccount                 custAccount;

#define.CurrentVersion(1)
#define.Version1(1)
#localmacro.CurrentList
    custAccount
#endmacro
}


public Object dialog()
{

DialogRunbase      dlg;
;

dlg = super(dlg);

dlg.caption("Change quotation customer account");


dlg.addText('Please select an alternative customer account');

dlgCust     = dlg.addField(typeid(CustAccount),'Customer account');

dlgCust.fieldControl().mandatory(true);

if(!dlgCust)
{
    error('Please fill out all mandatory fields');
}

return dlg;
}

void Fld2_1_lookup()
{
    Dialog                  dlg = this.dialog();
    SysTableLookup          sysTableLookup;
    QueryBuildDataSource    queryBuildDataSource;
    QueryBuildRange         queryBuildRange;
    Query                   query;
    Str                     TmpStr;
    Formrun                 fr = this.dialogModify().parmDialog();
    Object                  Control = fr.controlCallingMethod();


    FormStringControl              _control = control;
    ;

    sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tablenum(CustTable),_control);

    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldnum(CustTable, AccountNum),true);
    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldnum(CustTable, Name));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldnum(CustTable, NameAlias));

    query = new Query();

    queryBuildDataSource = query.addDataSource(tablenum(CustTable));

    tmpStr = 'ADAM001H';

    queryBuildRange = queryBuildDataSource.addRange(fieldnum(CustTable, InvoiceAccount));
    queryBuildRange.value(TmpStr);


    sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);

    sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
}

public void dialogPostRun(DialogRunbase dialog)
{

;

Super(dialog);
dialog.formRun().controlMethodOverload(true);
dialog.formRun().controlMethodOverloadObject(this);
}
```

Can you please tell me where I am going wrong here - in truth I do not really understand this override of the dialogPostRun method or the use of the ControlCallingMethod.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving `DialogRunbase dlg;` from method `dialog` to `ClassDeclaration`, removing `Dialog dlg = this.dialog();` and using `Object control = dlg.formRun().controlCallingMethod();` in method `fld2_1_lookup`. It should work.